# KDB Table enlist function call not running

Tags: kdb

I have a simple problem below

```
f2:{[x;y] 
    r:sum(x)*sum(y);
    r
 };
tm:([] pr:(100.01 100.02;100.03 100.04); rv:(15.72 55.64; 16.92 15.17 12.21 34.99))
f2 each [tm`rv][tm`pr]
```

The result I get is

```
{[x;y] 
    r:sum(x)*sum(y);
    r
 }[(15.72 55.64;16.92 15.17 12.21 34.99)'[(100.01 100.02;100.03 100.04)]]
```

The result I want is to add tm`rv and add tm`pr and multiply.

Answer (score 0):

```
tm
pr            rv                     
-------------------------------------
100.01 100.02 15.72 55.64            
100.03 100.04 16.92 15.17 12.21 34.99
```

Hi, you can sum each nested list then do the multiplication:

```
select result:(sum each pr)*sum each rv from tm
result  
--------
14274.14
15863.55
q)
```

But if you want to use your f2 function:{[x;y] r:sum(x)*sum(y); r }

You should do this:

```
f2'[tm`rv;tm`pr]
14274.14 15863.55
q)
```

' apply f2 over pairwise combinations of arguments

Comment: Slightly less going on with `exec f2'[rv;pr] from tm`.